# Xcode Update from 4.2 to 4.6 causing errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, breakpoints, xcode4.6

I've recently updated my `XCode` from `4.2 to 4.6` as I had an outdated iOS SDK.

However, after performing the update, When I try to run the app and press buttons, the iPhone app freezes, and returns me back to the XCode window with the errors. These are errors I have never seen before, as the App was working perfectly fine before the update. As I have never seen these errors before, I do not know what Information is needed for this error to be fixed. If I need more than these screenshots, please do tell.

What can I do to fix these errors?

**I don't have the rep to post pictures, this is why I am just posting the links.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihNLf.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYwJG.jpg (One of the threads)

Comment: post the error logs if any ?

Comment: Try to set the exception breakpoint and see on which line the app crashes.

Comment: Show us a full backtrack. The image you provide has a clipped one. A the bottom of the panel with the backtracks on, drag the slider all the way to the right. Also, show us any console output.

Comment: Have you tried product -> clean ?

Comment: are you running OS X 10.8.4?

Answer (score 0):

If the app freezes after you try to press a button then I would assume it's a problem with the linking between your an IBAction function and the onclick event of the button.

Unless I'm misunderstanding the issue, try setting a breakpoint in the function that's called when the button is cliked.

Comment: All the Break points are being caused by arrays (not just this one, but this is an example)...  http://imgur.com/rjSGfcU

Answer (score 0):

Beside suggestions of *nchinda* Check "***Enable Zombie Objects***" under Edit Scheme as this will report issues caused by bad excess or pre-releasing of an object, and check the Logs for issues. Also set break points on your IBAction to inspect more.